# form a string from characters

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

1. I need to form a string from 8 characters using (a-z) (A-Z) and (0-9) That is 62 characters in total.
   In an 8 character string there needs to be at least one digit, at least one lowercase letter, and at least one uppercase letter. No character repetition is allowed. How many ways are there to form such a password?

I came up with this answer while trying to understand the problem:
(62<sup>8</sup>-36<sup>8</sup>-36<sup>8</sup>-52<sup>8</sup>)*8!

I'm afraid my answer to question is not correct and I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong.

2. I need to form a string from 8 characters using (a-z) (A-Z) and (0-9), where the digits have to come before the letters. Repetition of characters is allowed, and I believe there can also be a string where there are only digits and where its all letters

This one I am really struggling with. Couldn't think of a way it could be expressed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: But what exactly is the question? Are you trying to count the number of ways the string can be formed?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to include it in the question

Comment: There is no repetition in the first part, so you need $\binom{62}{8}$ and similar for the excluded cases. You also need to include cases that were excluded twice (all uppercase, all lowercase, all numbers).

Comment: If repetitions are not allowed, then you can't use 62^8. You should use combinations as @DanielMathias mentioned. 

The reason is that once you fill the first space of the password, the number of characters available is 61, then you have 60 spaces, and so on. In fact, what you would require is permutation - but permutation and combinations are related by the '8!' you multiplied.

Answer (score 1):

For part one:

$$\frac{8*7*6*59!}{54!}$$

8 possible places for the decimal.
7 and then 6 places remain for each the upper and lower case.
59 possible characters remain. With 8 characters total and three from each class divide by $(59-5)!$.

Part two:

$$\sum_{i=0}^8 10^i *52^{8-i}$$

Sum of 8 iterations for 8 number of possible places the numerical part ends.

You will probably need a pen and paper or calculator if you want to find the final value of the sum.

Comment: Part one is incorrect. You are counting strings in which the first character is a digit, the second is an uppercase letter, and the third is a lowercase letter.

Comment: The solution has been edited and updated.